# Mock Redis, but can not find the result

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, redis, mocha.js, sinon

I'm currently doing unit test with mocha.js, sinon.js and chai.js.
When testing, I mock redis to createClient.

Here is the code I want to test:

```
async setAsync(key, value, ttl) {
    return await redisClient.setAsync(key, value).then((reply) => {
      consoleLogger.log(`redisClient set key[${key}] reply=${reply}`);
      console.log('RedisClient:', redisClient);

      if (ttl) {
        return redisClient.expireAsync(key, ttl).then(() => {
          return Promise.resolve();
        });
      }
      return Promise.resolve();
    });
  }
```

Here is my unit test:

```
sinon.stub(redis, 'createClient').returns({
  exists: function () {},
  set: function (key, value, cb) {
    console.log(`mocked set, request: ${key} -> ${value}`);
    return cb(null, 'OK');
  },
  setAsync: async function (key, value, ttl) {
    console.log(`mocked setAsync, request: ${key} -> ${value} -> ${ttl} `);

    if (ttl) {
      await sleep(100);
      return 'OK';
    } else {
      return 'OK';
    }
  },
  expireAsync: async function (key, ttl) {
    console.log(`mocked expireAsync, request: ${key} -> ${ttl}`);
    return 1;
  },
});



describe('redisDao', () => {
  afterEach(() => {
    sandbox.restore();
  });

  it('should set a key in Redis', async () => {
    const key = 'testKey';
    const value = 'testValue';
    const ttl = 3600;

    const redisDAO = new RedisDao();
    const result = await redisDAO.setAsync(key, value, ttl);

    console.log('----');
    console.log(result); 
    console.log('----');
    expect(result).to.equal('OK');
  });
 
 
});
```

Here is `console.log('RedisClient:', redisClient)` , when I run `npm run test`:

```
RedisClient: {
  exists: [Function: exists],
  set: [Function: set],
  setAsync: [Function: ret],
  expireAsync: [AsyncFunction: expireAsync],
    
    .....
    .....
}
```

Unit Test Error:

```
1) redisDao should set a key in Redis:
     AssertionError: expected undefined to equal 'OK'
      at Context.<anonymous> (test/unit/testRedisDAO.js:63:23)
```

I don't understand why RedisClient only get expireAsync, but setAsync don't. Can someone Answer me? Thank you.